# Having problems with urllib in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

Like the title says, I'm having problems with Python 3's urllib module.
My code:

```
import urllib.request

WORD_URL = "http://learnpythonthehardway.org/words.txt"

for word in urllib.request.urlopen(WORD_URL).read():
    WORDS.append(word.strip())
```

And my error is:

```
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

But the link works fine when I manually go to it in Google.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I got 404 on the browser too

Comment: When you get the URL right, `word` will iterate over each character, not each word, because `.read()` will return a string of the entire content.  You will want to `.splitlines()`.

Answer (score 0):

The URL does indeed link to a non-existing page.
Click: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/words.txt

Based on your writing I suppose you entered the URL in the Google search. That is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Switch

```
"http://learnpythonthehardway.org/words.txt"
```

to

```
"http://learncodethehardway.org/words.txt"
```

You should have a working program, but `.read()` returns a list of words. You'll have to parse through them and remove some characters.